# Python - print celulas em branco no excel

Tags: python, microsoft-excel

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma automação para conferir em uma planilha de excel quais clientes não fizeram o pagamento. O código em si funciona, mas só me mostra referente a ultima coluna da planilha, que no caso seria o ultimo mês do ano.
Segue abaixo código e modelo da planilha:

```
import openpyxl, smtplib, sys

#Abre a planilha e obtém o status do último pagamento.

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/temp/cobranca.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

lastCol = sheet.max_column
latestMonth = sheet.cell(row=1, column=lastCol).value

#Verifica o status de pagamento de cada cliente.

unpaidMembers = {}
for r in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    payment = sheet.cell(row=r, column=lastCol).value
    if payment != 'ok':
        cliente = sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value
        email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
        unpaidMembers[cliente] = email
        print('Linha:',r,'Coluna:',lastCol,'Cliente:',cliente,'Email:',email)
```

https://prnt.sc/utk4ef  modelo da planilha utilizada

Comment: Gustavo, boa tarde! Qual o funcionamento esperado?

Comment: Imonferrari, boa tarde! Gostaria de dar um print em todas as celulas que não estejam com o 'ok' e não somente as da última coluna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu código, você tem um `for` para as linhas, só estava faltando um `for` para as colunas:

```
import openpyxl, smtplib, sys

#Abre a planilha e obtém o status do último pagamento.

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('cobranca.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

lastCol = sheet.max_column
latestMonth = sheet.cell(row=1, column=lastCol).value

#Verifica o status de pagamento de cada cliente.

unpaidMembers = {}
for r in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
  for c in range(3, lastCol + 1):
    payment = sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value
    if payment != 'ok':
        cliente = sheet.cell(row=r, column=1).value
        email = sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value
        mes = sheet.cell(row=1, column=c).value
        unpaidMembers[cliente] = email
        print('Linha:',r,'Coluna:',c,'Cliente:',cliente,'Email:',email,'Mês:',mes)
```

Só adicionei um coluna para indicar o mês, mais se não for necessário é só tirar.

Comment: mateusalxd, boa tarde! Muito obrigado, não tinha pensando em fazer um para a coluna.